# How to install snapd on github codespaces?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyppeteer, codespaces, snap

I know that github provides ubuntu machines called codespaces. I've used one on my code which is using pyppeteer(the python version of puppeteer) to open up a browser and scrape the web

but the thing is I could only get pyppeteer to work with the snap install of chromium
now that snap is not installing anything on the VM I don't know how to fix pyppeteer

is there any way of installing snap on codespaces? or can I make pyppeteer work with something else that you've tried on an ubuntu machine?

I tried:
`sudo apt install snapd`
snapd is already the newest version (2.58+20.04.1).

`sudo apt install snap`
snap is already the newest version (2013-11-29-9).

** I just installed them before posting this

and when I try:
`sudo snap install chromium`
It gives me this error:
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/chromium: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory